# Petrov-Galerkin enrichment method for Darcy equation

Tags: finite-element, fenics

I was reading about Petrov-Galerkin Enrichment Method for Darcy equations. Here are a couple papers that discuss this in detail:

- [A Petrov–Galerkin enriched method: A mass conservative finite element method for the Darcy equation](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0045782507000059).
- [A Symmetric Nodal Conservative Finite Element Method for the Darcy Equation](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/080724381).

However, I am not sure I understand what they are doing completely and would like some help understanding how they are constructing these "multiscale" or enrichment functions.

From what I understand, it seems they are "enriching" the $P_1$ velocity by an $RT_0$, but what exactly does this mean? Specifically, what is meant when they "correct edge residuals"? Because I would like to implement this in something like FEniCS (if possible) but in order to do that I need to understand this method completely.